# How do you determine inclination of nouns?

Tags: склонение

I always see this simple tables, where inclination is determined very easy - you just look if it's feminine, masculine or neuter and then look at the ending of the word.

But it just doesn't work sometimes.
`"звено" - "звенья"` but `"зерно" - "зёрна"` and `"шило" - "шилья"`. Sometimes it works several ways like `"крыло" - "крылья"` but `"крылА"` works as well (although sounds a bit old-fashioned).

Is there some more general rule or I'll just have to memorize all this? I'm especially interested about "зерно" and "звено", they appear so similar!

Comment: wow, the correct plural of **шила - шилья** is a revelation to me, i've never heard it in a real life, people in my region say **шилА**

Comment: as far as зерно - звено are concerned, you may notice a cluster of consonants in зеРНо, зёРНья (зёРНЬЙА) is that much more difficult to pronounce due to 3 successive consonants, this could be part of the reason why such form of plural is unlikely

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are mixing things. If we speak about declension both зерно and звено decline in the same way.

> И. зерно, звено
>   Р. зерна, звена
>   Д. зерну, звену
>   В. зерно, звено
>   Т. зерном, звеном
>   П. о зерне, о звене.

So what is the problem? As for plural forms, крылья, звенья, (шила!, если два, три, четыре), шилья, зёрна, there's no general rule. You should consult a dictionary.

Comment: Yeah, I meant plural forms; I thought they are determined by inclination as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is more to declension than just the type. The type determines the endings but quite a few words also get suffixes added or replaced especially when switching into plural:

- муж - муж**ь**я
- стул - стул**ь**я
- кот**ёнок** - кот**ят**а
- мыш**он**ок - мыш**ат**а

(This type of suffix alteration is quite regular and applies to all animate nouns and the name of a mushroom опенок.)

- мать - мат**ер**и
- дочь - доч**ер**и

There are also volatile vowels:

- вет**е**р - ветра (compare to: катер - катера)

Quite a few masculine nouns get 'neuter' endings -а/-я: доктор**а**, учител**я**.

Given just the nominative singular form of a noun you can't reliably deduce its inflected forms. You need to know if the word has a volatile vowel or suffix alterations or irregular endings. Such information can be found in dictionaries such as *The Grammatical Dictionary of Russian* by Andrey Zalizniak. Or you can simply use software tools such as this one: http://morpher.ru/Demo.aspx

Comment: Interesting tool. It gives "директор" - "директора" but "конструктор" - "конструкторы".

Comment: @Amomum конструктор has two meanings:1. a game like LEGO and 2. a designer, developer, engineer, in the 1st one it only inflects with the -Ы ending, in the 2nd it can take both inflections, but in colloquial language leans towards -A